# How to CSS pairs of DIV text left/right of center

Tags: css, css-float

I'm having problems centering some divs, in which some should appear left of center, others right of center, and some on newlines. eg.

<div class="container">
<div class="leftofcenter">Mr</div>
<div class="leftofcenter">Firstname</div>
<div class="rightofcenter">Surname</div>
<div class="leftofcenter">Address</div>
<div class="leftofcenter">Town, </div>
<div class="rightofcenter">Postcode</div>
</div>

Should appear as (text lengths vary from block to block):

```
                                      Mr Firstname Surname
                                             Address
                                         Town, Postcode
```

I've tried various uses of floats, inline-boxes, and other clever stuff, but I can't work it out for the life of me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Let us see your CSS too

Comment: Could you point out which css you have, for now ?
In your exemple, everything is centered, I don't understand your question, probably.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/x7sor7ac/

Comment: or like this http://jsfiddle.net/x7sor7ac/2/

Comment: Looks like you should be using a table.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't have any CSS because Drupal is outputting my HTML without styling. @Cheslab your first example is close, except for the output on different lines, and the second example at http://jsfiddle.net/x7sor7ac/2 is closer still except for the "Mr" prefix which should appear on the same line as the "Firstname Surname" (as in my example).

Comment: If Omer Bonfil's answer does what you wanted, your question was not describing your request accurately. Your divs do not appear right or left of center. They are all centered and all you needed was a line breaking pattern.

Comment: Are you able to change html or just css?

Comment: Unfortunately tables are not an option as I can't change the HTML (and sometimes there could be 2 or 3 items on a line), though I do have the option of having CSS classes that identify each individual DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand this is what you want..

```
.container{
    text-align:center;  
}
.container>div{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; 
}
.rightofcenter+.leftofcenter{
    display:block;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzbs4Lax/

Comment: That looks exactly what I was after! I'm surprised that the CSS looks so simple. I also tried it without the vertical-align:top (I couldn't see what it was doing), and it still appears to work. It also appears to work fine if I change the .container>div to display:inline making it even simpler.

Comment: vertical-align:top makes the "inline-block" elements alignproperly next to each other when they have different heights, for me it's just a habit of writing it. changing it to inline works well because the content is text. changing your divs to spans would have saved you this rule as well since span is an inline element natively. Appreciate if you would accept the answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="center">
    Mr Firstname Surname
  </p>
  <p class="center">
    Address
  </p>
  <p class="center">
    Town, Postcode
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, except that I don't have the luxury of being able to change the HTML. All the elements I mentioned are already surrounded by DIVs, and I can't change that.